# Stop movement if transform.position.y == 0

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

Why does the following code not step the object's movement when its y coordinate reaches zero?

```
    public GameObject cube;
    private GameObject inst;
    public float speed=5;


    void Start () {
        inst = Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(0, 10.6f, 0),Quaternion.identity);
    }


    void Update () {

        inst.transform.Translate(speed * Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        if (inst.transform.position.y == 0)
        {
            speed = 0; //stop moving
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Y position is never EXACTLY 0.

Its for example 
5.5
next frame: 4.3
next frame: 3.1
next frame: 1.9
next frame: 0.7
next frame: -0.5

change the if to

```
if (inst.transform.position.y <= 0)
```

Then add:

```
inst.transform.position = new Vector3(inst.transform.position.x, 0, inst.transform.position.z);
```

next to:

```
speed = 0;
```